# getting cisco on the net

Tags: networking, cisco, rip

I'm trying to set up a Cisco test lab I have 
three routers and one switch:

1. Cisco 2501
2. Cisco 2513
3. Cisco 3620
4. Catalyst 1900

What I'm trying to do is to get the 2501 and 2513 on the net. 
Router #1 is the 2501;
router #2 is the 2513.

I have all of the cable and adapters needed to get started.

Router 1 is connected to Router 2 with a serial cable; they use 10.0.0.0 "R1 10.0.0.2/8 and R2 10.0.0.1/8".

Router 1 acts as a DHCP server; its pool is 100.0.0.0. Router 1 is connected to the Catalys 1900 using eth0.

Router 2 is the DCE and the clock rate is set. Router 2 is connected to my home network on eth0.

RIP version 2 is being used.

I can ping router1 and 2 from my home network (192.168.1.0 "mycomputer 192.168.1.121/24").

I can ping a computer on the 100.0.0.0 network "testcomp 100.0.0.11/8".
I can ping google from the following devices: mycomputer and router 2.

However, I cannot ping Google from the following devices: testcomp and router 1

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I need every computer on the 100.0.0.0 network to be able to get onto the internet; here is my configuration:

```
        Router 2


    ACRS-R2#show config
    Using 602 out of 32762 bytes
    !
    version 11.3
    service timestamps debug uptime
    service timestamps log uptime
    no service password-encryption
    !
    hostname ACRS-R2
    !
    enable secret 5 <REMOVED>
    !
    !
    !
    interface Ethernet0
     ip address 192.168.1.244 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface Serial0
     ip address 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
     no ip mroute-cache
     no fair-queue
     clockrate 64000
    !
    interface Serial1
     no ip address
     shutdown
    !
    interface TokenRing0
     no ip address
     shutdown
    !
    router rip
     version 2
     network 10.0.0.0
     network 192.168.1.0
    !
    ip default-gateway 192.168.1.254
    ip classless
    !
    !
    line con 0
    line aux 0
    line vty 0 4
     login
    !
    end

    ACRS-R2#
    Gateway of last resort is 192.168.1.254 to network 0.0.0.0

    R    100.0.0.0/8 [120/1] via 10.0.0.2, 00:00:04, Serial0
    C    10.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, Serial0
    C    192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0
    R*   0.0.0.0/0 [120/1] via 192.168.1.254, 00:00:06, Ethernet0
    ACRS-R2#

    Router 1

    ACRS-R1#show conf
    Using 790 out of 32762 bytes
    !
    version 12.2
    service timestamps debug uptime
    service timestamps log uptime
    no service password-encryption
    !
    hostname ACRS-R1
    !
    enable secret 5 $ <REMOVED>
    !
    ip subnet-zero
    ip name-server 192.168.1.254
    ip dhcp excluded-address 100.0.0.1 100.0.0.10
    !
    ip dhcp pool ip100
       network 100.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
       dns-server 192.168.1.254
       default-router 100.0.0.1
       domain-name acrsnet
       netbios-name-server 192.168.1.254
       lease infinite
    !
    !
    !
    !
    interface Ethernet0
     ip address 100.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
    !
    interface Serial0
     ip address 10.0.0.2 255.0.0.0
    !
    interface Serial1
     no ip address
     shutdown
    !
    router rip
     version 2
     network 10.0.0.0
     network 100.0.0.0
    !
    ip default-gateway 10.0.0.1
    ip classless
    no ip http server
    !
    !
    !
    line con 0
    line aux 0
    line vty 0 4
     login
    !
    end

    ACRS-R1#
    Gateway of last resort is 10.0.0.1 to network 0.0.0.0

    C    100.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, Ethernet0
    C    10.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, Serial0
    R    192.168.1.0/24 [120/1] via 10.0.0.1, 00:00:09, Serial0
    R*   0.0.0.0/0 [120/2] via 10.0.0.1, 00:00:09, Serial0
    ACRS-R1#
```

Comment: 100.0.0.0/8 is an IP range that is routable to the internet. I would try changing that to something internal. See (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything evident in your configs that would be causing the problem. Can you run a trace route from the 100.0.0.0 network all the way through the routers and to an external ip address? Can you resolve the name www.google.com from the 100.0.0.0 network?

Comment: @joeqwerty i changed the network to 11.0.0.0 when i ran the trace route it failed when it got to `2 launchmodem (192.168.1.254) 16 msec 16 msec 16 msec`

Comment: As user70089 stated, your modem probably doesn't have a route to the 11 network. You'll need to add a satic route on the modem for the 11 network.

Comment: @joeqwerty my modem has a route to 11.0.0.0

Comment: What is that route?

Comment: @joeqwerty I ran a trace route today when the trace route starts it hits 10.0.0.1 and then 192.168.1.254 the modem after that nothing happens trace route prints out ****** and then it just goes back to the router command prompt

Comment: @joeqwerty i configed eth0 to use dhcp and i was able to ping google.com but i need to be able to use a static ip address

Comment: I haven't been following this. Where did you run the trace from? What DHCP address is assigned to the host?

Answer (score 0):

How is your home network connected to the Internet? Is 192.168.1.254 your broadband router? If so, that sounds like it might need a route back to your 100.0.0.0 network via 192.168.1.244

As someone mentioned above, as 100.0.0.0/8 is a public address range, you might be better referring to RFC1918 and using one of the other private address ranges from there (perhaps making the 100 network 172.16.0.0/16 or similar).

Comment: @user70089 my home network is connected to the internet using a at&t dsl modem yes 192.168.1.254 is the ip address of the modem

Comment: Do you have NAT set up? Your DSL gateway will, probably, only allow NATing for a 192.168.1.0/24, so you will need to NAT yout 100.0.0.0/8 netblock into that (then to get NATed again, as it egresses through your DSL router). I'd also consider changing the 100/8 network to a /16 out of 172.16/12